# CLI options not detected for pytest plugin

Tags: python, plugins, pytest, python-3.5

I'm doing some development work on `pytest-testrails`. I have tested it just fine with a project that uses Python 2.7 but I am seeing some behaviour that I don't know how to debug when using a project that uses Python 3.5.

I am loading it via:

`pip install /path/to/plugin/on/my/filesystem`

When I run `py.test --trace-config` I see that the plugin is definitely being loaded:

`setuptools registered plugins:
  pytest-django-2.9.1 at /Users/chartjes/mozilla/normandy/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pytest_django/plugin.py
  pytest-mock-0.11.0 at /Users/chartjes/mozilla/normandy/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pytest_mock.py
  pytest-testrail-0.0.4 at /Users/chartjes/mozilla/normandy/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pytest_testrail/__init__.py`

But when I set one of the CLI options:

`py.test --testrail=contract-tests/testrail.cfg ...`

py.test complains that it doesn't recognize the arguments

`usage: py.test [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]
py.test: error: unrecognized arguments: --testrail=contract-tests/testrail.cfg
  inifile: /Users/chartjes/mozilla/normandy/pytest.ini
  rootdir: /Users/chartjes/mozilla/normandy`

Any thoughts on how to debug what might be going on here?

Comment: have you tried `py.test --help` ?

Comment: I have, it doesn't show the CLI options like I am expecting

Comment: How did you add new cmdline option in your plugin?
Please show the code.